# Characteristic function of pdf

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The pdf is:
$$P_x(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4\pi}\ln\Biggl(\frac{\tan\frac{\phi_2(x)}{2}}{\tan\frac{\phi_1(x)}{2}}\Biggr)$$ for $|x|\leq 1$. I want to calculate Characteristic function of following pdf. How to proceed, please help.

[image]

Comment: Next time, please try to type your equations using Latex syntax.

Comment: What are the definitions of $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$ ?